# How to stress test a local webapp?

Tags: web, benchmarking, stress-testing

Today a want to stress-test my local webapp but I don't know how.
I currently use a simple shell script

```shell
#!/bin/sh

while [ true ]
do
        curl http://localhost:5000/cabinet-dentaire-nice/cab &> /dev/null
done
```

But this is not exactly what i want.

I want to test it with a lot of requests in the same time and not a fast squence of requests.
How can i do it ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apachebench-to-do-load-testing-on-an-ubuntu-13-10-vps

Comment: If it's a webapp can't you simply make calls to your onclick functions and/or simulate normal flow through the programm?